# Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.

Tags: node.js, express, vue.js

select_value: function (del) {
            var self = this;

```
        self.$http.post("/sales/team_leader_id_table", {"id": del,}).then(function(res){
            var parentdata = res.body.result[0];            

        },function(err){
            alert(err);
        });



    },
```

//services 
router.post('/team_leader_id_table', function (req, res, next) {

```
for (var i = 0; i < req.body.id.length; i++) {
    console.log('SELECT * FROM `user` where id = "'+req.body.id[i]+'" ');
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM `user` where id = "'+req.body.id[i]+'" ', function (error, results, fields) {
        if (!error) {
            console.log(results);
            res.json({"status": "ok", "result": results});
        } else {
            res.json({"status": "failed", "message": error.message});
        }
    });

}
```

});

```
//error 
C:\Users\HP 840 G3\Desktop\ERP\sp_workspace\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:80
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:489:11)
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:496:3)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\HP 840 G3\Desktop\ERP\sp_workspace\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:719:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (C:\Users\HP 840 G3\Desktop\ERP\sp_workspace\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:164:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (C:\Users\HP 840 G3\Desktop\ERP\sp_workspace\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:250:15)
    at Query._callback (C:\Users\HP 840 G3\Desktop\ERP\sp_workspace\routes\sales.js:1662:21)
    at Query.Sequence.end (C:\Users\HP 840 G3\Desktop\ERP\sp_workspace\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:88:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (C:\Users\HP 840 G3\Desktop\ERP\sp_workspace\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:139:8)
    at Query.EofPacket (C:\Users\HP 840 G3\Desktop\ERP\sp_workspace\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:123:8)
    at Protocol._parsePacket (C:\Users\HP 840 G3\Desktop\ERP\sp_workspace\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:279:23)
    at Parser.write (C:\Users\HP 840 G3\Desktop\ERP\sp_workspace\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:76:12)
    at Protocol.write (C:\Users\HP 840 G3\Desktop\ERP\sp_workspace\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:39:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\HP 840 G3\Desktop\ERP\sp_workspace\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:103:28)
    at emitOne (events.js:115:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:264:12)
```

Comment: don't use res.json in for loop, accumulate the result in for loop and then use res.json after for loop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-to-the-client)

Comment: If you want to call async functions in a loop, I recommend you to use `eachOf` from `async` package.

See the documentation here, http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachOf

Answer (score 0):

You cannot loop responses per one request, it's illegal in Express, returning more than one response per one request will crash your NodeJS (Express will return an *unhandledException*). Loop, insert the data into an array then res send values from the array (out of the loop, of course).